# lm13700 as Diode laser voltage to current converter

Tags: signal-processing, mixed-signal

I generated two Signals,   one using dac7611 (ramped signal with fre = 0.04hz ) and the other one, using AD9833 DDS (sin wave with fre = 32 KHz) then  generated signals  added using ad620an. Is this possible to convert Voltage to current using Lm13700 to power up two Diode laser without losing the precision of 0.01 Hz of frequency of DDS ? if Not what is the better option?

Comment: Which LASER diode spec? Are you aware of the hysteresis of the lasing current threshold?

Comment: yeah, I know, main part of my question is about the accuracy of final signal, does LM13700 final signal preserve the accuracy?